# Setting Bool in different classes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have the following code where after a bool is true I want to add a drawing to my rect.  here is the code I have but for some reason it is either not setting the bool or calling the setNeedsDisplay.  Am I referencing to the other class properly? thanks

//in AppController.m

```
-(IBAction)colorToggle:(id)sender
{
    if ([colorFilter state] == NSOnState) 
    {
        CutoutView *theView = [[CutoutView alloc] init];
        [theView setFilterEnabled:YES];

    }
```

}

//in cutoutView.m

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [[[NSColor blackColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0.9]set];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect); 

    //this is what i want to be drawn when my bool is true and update the drawRect        
    if (filterEnabled == YES) {
        NSRectFillUsingOperation(NSMakeRect(100, 100, 300, 300), NSCompositeClear);
        [self update];
    }
}

-(void)update
{
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, you know how not every UILabel is the same? Like, you can remove one UILabel from a view without all the others disappearing too? Well, your CutoutView is the same way. When you write `CutoutView *theView = [[CutoutView alloc] init];` there, that creates a **new** CutoutView that isn't displayed anywhere. You need to talk to your *existing* CutoutView (probably by hooking up an outlet, but there are any number of perfectly valid designs that will accomplish this goal).

Comment: Thanks! that made perfect sense

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to call the `drawRect:` method, it should looks like this:

```
CutoutView *theView = [[CutoutView alloc] init];
[theView setFilterEnabled:YES];
[theView setNeedsDisplay];
```

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html):

> When the actual content of your view changes, it is your
>   responsibility to notify the system that your view needs to be
>   redrawn. You do this by calling your view’s setNeedsDisplay or
>   setNeedsDisplayInRect: method of the view.

Comment: Thanks I get what you mean but even when I use `[theView setNeedsDisplay:YES];` it still isint redrawing the rect.  Is my bool statement correct?