# replace value of variable in another class

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have classes
*ColorViewController
*DrawRectangle

In ColorViewController.h:

```
#import "DrawRectangle.h"
@interface ColorViewController : UIViewController {
DrawRectangle *DrawRectangle;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) DrawRectangle *DrawRectangle;
```

And in DrawRectangle.h:

```
@interface DrawRectangle : UIView {
CGFloat redc;
}
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat redc;
```

I have also added the DrawRectangle class in ViewController.xib to one of UIView.

I want to change the value of CGFloat redc from file ColorViewController.m
I'm doing it this way:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
CGFloat myfloat = 1.0;
self.DrawRectangle.redc = myfloat;
```

I'm calling NSLog with this 'redc' in DrawRectangle, but it says 0.0000000 each time.

How can I replace the value of 'redc' from ViewController? I don't think I need to use NSNotification, there must be easier way if I have the DrawRectangle loaded into ViewController.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting Bool in different classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004502/setting-bool-in-different-classes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your object hasn't been instantiated yet. Try:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGFloat myfloat = 1.0;
    [drawRectangle setRedc:myfloat];
}
```

You should also avoid naming your objects the same name as the class as a general programming practice. I Would suggest renaming the object to `drawRectangle`.

You also need to hook up your drawRectangle object in your xib

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet DrawRectangle *drawRectangle;
```

Comment: Why so what? Is your object synthesized? `@synthesize redc;` and `@synthesize DrawRectangle;`

Comment: Yes, I have redc synthesized in DrawRectangle.m and DrawRectangle in ViewController of course

Comment: I have now `[self setDrawRectangle:[[DrawRectangle alloc] init]];
    
    CGFloat myfloat = 1.0;
    NSLog(@"%f", myfloat);
    
    [drawRectangle setRedc:myfloat];` but doesn't work still

Comment: if that is your code, your NSLog should output `1.000000000` because you are just outputting the `CGFloat` you just created

Comment: Yes, but I have two NSLog... the second one is located in DrawRectangle.m    `NSLog(@"Value %f",redc);`

Comment: Where in `DrawRectangle` is it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9754/discussion-between-konrad-kolasa-and-coldlogic)